# cannot send mail using php mail function

Tags: php, email, smtp

Im trying to use PHP mail on my local computer,  but its just not working. I am using the standard script from the php website:

PHP error I'm getting

```
SMTP server response: 550 Error sending message: Error: FROM address is invalid
```

actual PHP

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

i downloaded a local mail server, argosoft.  it says the service URL is http://services.argosoft.com/RelayService/Service.asmx . I assume this is what i put in php.ini.

php ini.

```
 For Win32 only.
 SMTP = services.argosoft.com/RelayService/Service.asmx
 smtp_port = 25
```

Comment: I had what seems to be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429317/strange-behavior-in-php-mail-function-address-does-not-exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this error before, and I believe all you have to do is change the email `webmaster@example.com` to a real email. Make sure you send it to a real email as well.

Comment: maybe your meant to change something else in php.ini. are you meant to change sendmail_from

Answer (score 0):

Replace @example.com with real email addresses.

and in PHP.ini set

```
SMTP = localhost
```

Comment: I get this error when i set SMTP to localhost:

Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: Run this in cmd, `netstat -an` do you see 127.0.0.1:25?

Comment: i see a lot of 127.0.0.1 but none with port 25.

Comment: Then the server is not listening locally, make sure the server is running, or maybe you should try something like http://www.hmailserver.com/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, a number of mail systems have trouble with the carriage return `\r`.  You might want to modify your `$header` to use only the new line character `\n`.  See if that works.

Also, you might want to try using the full From header:

`From: Some Name Here <real_email@notAnExample.com>`

Comment: I know this is old, but I thought I'd share the knowledge anyway: According to RFC2822, header fields are to be seperated by a CRLF, that is "\r\n".